# Pinning latitude longitude on a ski map

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, openstreetmap, coordinate-transformation

I have a map of a mountainous landscape, http://skimap.org/data/989/60/1218033025.jpg. It contains a number of known points, the lat-longs of which can be easily found out using Google maps. I wish to be able to pin any latitude longitude coordinate on the map, of course within the bounds of the landscape.

For this, I tried an approach that seems to be largely failing. I assumed the map to be equivalent to an aerial photograph of the Swiss landscape, without any info about the altitude or other coordinates of the camera. So, I assumed the plane perpendicular to the camera lens normal to be Ax+By+Cz-d=0.

I attempt to find the plane constants, using the known points. I fix my origin at a point, with z=0 at the sea level. I take two known points in the landscape, and using the equation for a line in 3D, I find the length of the projection of this line segment joining the two known points, on the plane. I multiply it by another constant K to account for the resizing of this length on a static 2d representation of this 3D image. The length between the two points on a 2d static representation of this image on this screen can be easily found in pixels, and the actual length of the line joining the two points, can be easily found, since I can calculate the distance between the two points with their lat-longs, and their heights above sea level.

So, I end up with an equation directly relating the distance between the two points on the screen 2d representation, lets call it Ls, and the actual length in the landscape, L. I have many other known points, so plugging them into the equation should give me values of the 4 constants. For this, I needed 8 known points (known parameters being their name, lat-long, and heights above sea level), one being my orogin, and the second being a fixed reference point. The rest 6 points generate a system of 6 linear equations in A^2, B^2, C^2, AB, BC and CA. Solving the system using a online tool, I get the result that the system has a unique solution with all 6 constants being 0.

So, it seems that the assumption that the map is equivalent to an aerial photograph taken from an aircraft, is faulty. Can someone please give me some pointers or any other ideas to get this to work? Do open street maps have a Mercator projection?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this impossible to do in an automatic way. The skimap should be considered as an image rather than a map, a map is an projection of the real world into one plane, since this doesn't fit skimaps very well they are drawn instead.

The best way is probably to manually define a lot of points in the skimap with known or estimated coordinates and use them to estimate the points betwween. To get an acceptable result you probably have to assign coordinates to each pixel in the skimap.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following: http://magazin.unic.com/en/2012/02/16/making-of-interactive-mobile-piste-map-by-laax/

I am solving the exact same issue. It is pretty hard and lots of maths. Taking me a few weeks to solve it. Interpolation is the key as well with lots of manual mapping. I would say that for a ski mountain it will take at least 1000/1500 points to be able to get the very basic. So, not a trivial task unless you can automate the collection of these points (what I am doing!) ;)